# Script only runs once

Tags: javascript

This is a script that [should] refresh a page, find the price, and if the price is lower than what the user specifies, buys it. If the price is higher, it refreshes the page and does it again until the price is found:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('b');
var price;
var lp;
var sp;
var setSnipe = false;
var loaded = false;
for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    console.log(tags[i].innerHTML);
    if( tags[i].innerHTML.indexOf('R$') !== -1) {
        if (i==5){
            var price = tags[i].innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0];
            setSnipe = confirm("Lowest price: R$" + price +". Set a sniper?");
        } else {
        }
    } else {
    }
}
if (setSnipe == true) {
    lp = prompt("Snipe Price?");
    refresh();
}

function refresh() {
    location.reload(true);
    setTimeout('checkSnipe()', 3000);
}

function checkSnipe() {
    var tagss = document.getElementsByTagName('b');
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        console.log(tagss[i].innerHTML);
        if( tagss[i].innerHTML.indexOf('R$') !== -1) {
            if (i==5){
                var price = tagss[i].innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0];
                price = Number(price);
                if (price<=lp){
                    alert("Snipe Found!");
                } else {
                    alert("No snipe");
                    refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, it only runs once then stops. Any advice/help?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Surely there's a better way to do this... unless this is a homework assignment.

Comment: @Jeff Not a HW assignment, making it for myself for roblox.com. Not the best scripter obviously :/

Comment: Instead of refreshing the page, did you consider making an AJAX request and refreshing the page content?

Comment: @Alex It's ok, we've seen a lot worse ;) I was critiquing your method more than your scripting knowhow, which you obviously have based off your sample code. While I don't know the exact nature to this program, I would suggest trying to avoid a page refresh; that will make things a lot smoother. Also, using an anonymous function (`function(){checkSnipe()}`) instead of a string in the `setTimeout` function is generally good practice.

Answer (score 2):

When you refresh, your code does not exist any more. You have a new page, with new code. When you understand this, it becomes obvious that nonexistent code won't run.

Comment: As long as the code is outside the `iframe`, yes. But accessing elements inside the `iframe` (as well as reloading the `iframe`) need a bit more work. However, using AJAX instead would be much easier and nicer.

Comment: Thanks, never heard of AJAX but ill get on it.

Comment: I should say, using AJAX supported by a nice library like jQuery would be nicer. Doing AJAX by hand is kind of painful and full of pitfalls.

Comment: Here's what im getting at: [ http://www.roblox.com/Poison-Horns-item?id=62152671 ]. If you could point me in the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your code persist even if the user refreshes the browser. Plus, check your code again, it might have some logicl error (you might have misplaced braces in the if-else part).